# Restore task switcher menu on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, application-switcher, openbox

My system is Lubuntu, freshly installed, and has been working fine for a couple of days.

I don't know since when, but when I press `Alt+Tab` I cannot see my task switcher. Instead, some window border is highlighted. But neither the window content, nor the application icon is provided, it is useless for task selecting.

How can I get the original task switcher back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's strange that this setting would change out of its own accord but you should be able to revert it by manually editing the configuration file of your window manager (openbox):

1. Create a backup copy of your existing openbox configuration:

   ```
   cp "~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml" "~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc-old.xml"
   ```
2. Open `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` in a text editor of your choice
3. Find the section in your configuration file corresponding to the following snippet:

   ```
   <keybind key="A-Tab">
     <action name="NextWindow">
     <dialog>none</dialog>
     </action>
   </keybind>
   <keybind key="A-S-Tab">
     <action name="PreviousWindow">
     <dialog>none</dialog>
     </action>
   </keybind>
   ```
4. In both instances, replace `<dialog>none</dialog>` with `<dialog>list</dialog>` (vertical list of window icons and window titles) or `<dialog>icons</dialog>` (horizontal list of window icons)
5. Update your current openbox session by executing `openbox --reconfigure`

---

Reference:

http://urukrama.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/reverting-to-the-old-alt-tab-dialog-in-openbox-3-5/

Comment: OP should also back up lubuntu-rc.xml first, and then, after editing as you've suggested, run `openbox --reconfigure` from a terminal to get the changes to take effect. Otherwise, a logout, login or a restart of Openbox is required. The nice thing about `openbox --reconfigure` is that it does a bit of "parsing" and let's you know if it finds something smelly.

Comment: @DKBose Ah, yes, completely forgot about `reconfigure`. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: No problem! Nice to see you helping out Lubuntu/Openbox users. I've started using Lubuntu and quite like it. Sometimes, I even choose the Openbox session at login time.